# How can I remove HTML elements inside a UL using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, client-side

I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="message" id="stats-results">
   <li>DS1 Records: <span id="ds1Count"></span></li>
   <li>DEV Records: <span id="devCount"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Is there an easy way for me to completely remove the `li` elements from the `ul` using jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There a method just for that, [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$('#stats-results').empty();
```

> Description: Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements
>   from the DOM.

No need for "tricks".

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#stats-results").html("");
```

This will remove all li elements

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('ul.message li').remove();`